# how to convert json of this format to csv with jq

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have a json file that is formatted in this way:

```
{"key1": "value1"}
{"key2": "value2"}
{"key3": "value3"}
```

I would like to convert this json to csv. However, the keys in all the objects in the file are not the same. I have a list of all the possible keys but some of them may be missing in any json object.  So if that is the case I would like to just insert a null value for that column.

How can I convert a json file formatted this way to the csv that I'd like?

Update:
Here is an example file called objects.json

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
{"key1": "value3", "key2": "value4", "key3": "value5"}
{"key1": "value6", "key2": "value7", "key4": "value8"}
```

Each object is on a new line of the file.

I have a json file called allkeys.json with an object that contains all the possible keys with null values:

`{"key1": null, "key2": null, "key3": null, "key4": null}`

I would like to convert example.json into a CSV file with all columns and would have null values for objects with any missing columns.

So my desired output is:

```
key1,key2,key3,key4
value1,value2,,
value3,value4,value5,
value6,value7,,value8
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines more closely by giving a complete example, including a "list of all the possible keys", and the expected output.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Try it [HERE](https://jsonlint.com)

Comment: @dawg it is how our data is output, i have the option of using sed to easily turn it into a json array with all the objects but am not sure if it is necessary

Answer (score 1):

You need to read all the data in your file to determine what set of keys are common to all objects, then output those keys and values if the object contained them. It would be easiest to slurp the data in then process.

```
$ jq -sr '([.[] | keys[]] | unique) as $keys | $keys, (.[] | [.[$keys[]]]) | @csv' input.json
"key1","key2","key3"
"value1",,
,"value2",
,,"value3"
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/IpdnCcRqDc)

Comment: The OP says "I have a list of all the possible keys" so slurping should not be necessary.  Even if the keys must be inferred from the JSON, a two-pass solution would be an alternative to slurping....

Answer (score 0):

If understood the problem correctly, what you can do is have a json file with all the keys set to null and then merge it with the file that has missing keys. You will then have a new json file with all the keys, which you can later convert to csv as usual. This can be done using `jq` `add` as in this example:

```
echo '{"key1":null}{"key2":null}{"key3":null}{"key4":null}{"key5":null}' > allkeys.json

echo '{"key1":"value1"}{"key2":"value2"}{"key3":"value3"}' > update.json

jq -s add allkeys.json update.json
```

output:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": null,
  "key5": null
}
```

adding conversion to csv:

```
jq -s add allkeys.json update.json | jq -r  '[.[]] | @csv'
```

output:

```
"value1","value2","value3",,
```

Comment: I did as you said and it merged the keys but when I then try to convert to csv, it doesn't add the commas for null columns. Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: @fraoudas: Pipe into `[.[]] | @csv`

Comment: @fraoudas, as mentioned by peak, you can then pipe the result to csv. I have updated the answer to include the conversion step.

Comment: I was mistaken, when I merge the keys it only does so for one object in the file. As a result when I pipe it to csv there is only one row.  Do you know why that is?

Comment: please update the question with samples of the json files and the desired output and we'll work it out

Comment: @Jayvee I've updated the question with an example and my desired output

Answer (score 0):

> I have a list of all the possible keys

Let's suppose this list is available as a JSON array of strings, e.g. as $keys.  Then using the following jq filter has several advantages, including efficiency (no use of the -s option), and no loss of data (relative to $keys):

```
$keys, (inputs | [.[$keys[]]]) | @csv
```

Example usage:

```
< input.json jq -nr --argjson keys '["key1","key2","key3","key4"]' -f program.jq
```

#### Output

```
"key1","key2","key3","key4"
"value1",,,
,"value2",,
,,"value3",
```

#### Two-pass solution

If the keys must be inferred from the data, it may still be worth considering a two-pass solution as this would avoid "slurping" the data.  In any case, if a two-pass solution is adopted, the above solution could be used for the second part, with the first part like this:

```
jq -nc 'reduce inputs as $x (null; . + $x) | keys_unsorted' input.json
```

So in a bash-like environment, you'd have:

```
<input.json jq -nr \
  --argjson keys "$(< input.json jq -nc 'reduce inputs as $x (null; . + $x) | keys_unsorted')" '
   $keys, (inputs | [.[$keys[]]]) | @csv
'
```

Comment: It's not bash-specific; it should work as-is in `sh` too, and therefore possibly in others too.